# Setting up a one-time installer using Apple's PackageMaker

Tags: macos, packagemaker

I'm a newbie at this so I'll explain what I did so far:

1. Open `PackageMaker` and drag my `MyApp` from `/Applications` into the left sidebar
2. Changed the owner/group for MyApp to root/admin and `rwxrwxr-x`
3. Created a `postinstall` shell script and selected it in the Scripts tab

So now, how do I add that executable (Adobe AIR Installer) that I want to run 1 time (on first install) only? Do I drag it into that left sidebar also? I tried doing that but it gives it a destination of `/Applications`, which I don't want. I want it extracted to a temp location, installed, and deleted. Also, how do I reference it from the shell script? Would I use the `open` command to run it? Hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add it to your package resources folder, then run it using from your shell script:

```
open -a /path/to/the/air/installer.app
```

Comment: Any tips to how to create a resources folder and script?